# Google play game services samples android import

Tags: android, google-play-games

I downloaded the zip from https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples and noticed that this is not ready to import, that means I can't import this samples.

So my question is: **What should I do to be able to import the samples?**

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for building and running the samples are at https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples#how-to-run-a-sample